# Is it possible to name an anonymous file socket?

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, file-descriptors

Suppose I perform the following command:

```
python3 foo.py
```

> Usage: foo ...

Next, I use redirection:

```
python3 <(foo.py)
```

> Usage: 63 ...
> (because the file descriptor assigned is `/dev/fd/63`)

My arg library uses introspection to know itself (apparently), so I'd like to provide it access to that info.  Is it possible to tag the anonymous file descriptor somehow?

Comment: You might/should be able to have Python look at the path to its relevant files, see if they are symbolic links and, if so, show the target of those symlinks with `os.readlink()`.

Comment: No, not with process substitution, which is what you're using. You would have to explicitly create and use a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe)